# Open the googleVis chart editor from a bootstrap modal

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, bootstrap-modal, googlevis

I would like to display a `googleVis` table in a bootstrap modal, also including a button to open the google chart editor. Like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(googleVis)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  actionButton("openModal", "Open modal"), 
  bsModal("modal", "Google Charts", "openModal", 
          htmlOutput("gvistable"))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$gvistable <- renderGvis({
    gvisTable(iris[1:2, 1:2], 
              options = list(gvis.editor = "Editor"))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The problem occurs when I open the google chart editor (by clicking on the "Editor" button in the modal). This opens another modal, and this one is behind the first one. How could I get the google chart editor stacked on the first modal ?

Answer (score 0):

This works by setting a `z-index` to the class `.google-visualization-charteditor-dialog` :

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".google-visualization-charteditor-dialog {z-index: 1000000}"))), 
  actionButton("openModal", "Open modal"), 
  bsModal("modal", "Google Charts", "openModal", 
          htmlOutput("gvistable"))
))
```

But there is an issue in the "Customize" tab of the editor: the menus are hidden.

Here is a solution without using `shinyBS`:

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".google-visualization-charteditor-dialog {z-index: 1050}"))
  ), 
  actionButton("openModal", "Open modal", 
               "data-toggle"="modal", "data-target"="#modal"), 
  tags$div(
    id = "modal", 
    class="modal fade", 
    tags$div(
      class="modal-dialog",
      tags$div(class="modal-content", 
               tags$div(
                 class="modal-header",
                 tags$button(
                   type="button", class="close", "data-dismiss"="modal",
                   HTML("&times;")
                 )
               ),
               tags$div(
                 class="modal-body",
                 htmlOutput("gvistable")
               ),
               tags$div(
                 class="modal-footer",
                 tags$button(
                   type="button", class="btn btn-default", "data-dismiss"="modal",
                   "Close"
                 )
               )
      )
    )
  )
))
```